# python requests - can not get body at 2nd request

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to scrape data, but I can only request successfully the 1st time, when I re-run, I cannot get the body again.

my code:

```
url="http://www.carparts.com/results/?N=0&Nr=AND%28universal%3A0%29&Ntk=Main&Ntx=mode+matchallany&Nty=1&PN=0+5727&VN=4294953018+4294962799+4294962221+4294957507+4294965468&universal=0"
request_headers = {
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0",
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate,post-check=0, pre-check=0",
"Content-Length":"22035",
"keep_alive":"false",
"Content-Type":"text/html; charset=UTF-8",
"Vary":"Accept-Encoding",
"Pragma":"no-cache"
}

pageSkimData = requests.get(url, headers=request_headers)        
treeSkimData = html.fromstring(pageSkimData.content)
```

Comment: is your request within a loop? so you are constantly sending requests? can you provide the "error" of your second attempt along with the status code?

Comment: I just try to run this code 2 times. at 2nd time, it can not get data in specific div. it is not error. it is successful.  But the result data i want, it does not generate in 2nd time. i tried with Postman, browser it is ok.

Comment: it also generates page content but it is not like the 1st time. so i can not get the right element.

Comment: So what do you get the second time?  It's going to be hard to diagnose without details of how it fails and what you expected to see instead.

Comment: What are you trying to get and what html gets returned on failure?

Comment: at the 1st time , i can get the div class="result" it contains the information i want, but at the 2nd time , that div is not generated again.

Comment: What do you want to scrape from the page?When I go the the webpage I don't see any dev with that class

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me also, once I made an initial request the source changed slightly for all subsequent requests, to get the data you could forget about the results and use the *product* divs:

```
pageSkimData = requests.get(url, headers=request_headers)
treeSkimData = html.fromstring(pageSkimData.content)
print(pageSkimData.content)
for prod in treeSkimData.xpath("//div[@class='product icon-chevron-small-right prodwithad clearfix']"):
    print(prod.xpath("./div[@class='producttitle']/h2/a/text()")[0])
    for li in prod.xpath("//ul[@class='product-feature-list']/li/span"):
        print(li.xpath("./strong/text()")[0] + li.xpath("./span/text()")[0])
```

Output:

```
 Color/ Finish:White
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-WH
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-BL
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H3
Part Number:H3P
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Yellow
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-YW
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H7
Part Number:H7L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9006
Part Number:9006H
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PR
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9007
Part Number:9007L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H1
Part Number:H1L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Pink
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PI
Availability: In Stock

Plasmaglow Light Bulb - Blue, Direct Fit                                                
 Color/ Finish:White
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-WH
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-BL
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H3
Part Number:H3P
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Yellow
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-YW
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H7
Part Number:H7L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9006
Part Number:9006H
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PR
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9007
Part Number:9007L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H1
Part Number:H1L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Pink
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PI
Availability: In Stock

Plasmaglow Light Bulb - Purple, Direct Fit                                              
 Color/ Finish:White
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-WH
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-BL
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H3
Part Number:H3P
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Yellow
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-YW
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H7
Part Number:H7L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9006
Part Number:9006H
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PR
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9007
Part Number:9007L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H1
Part Number:H1L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Pink
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PI
Availability: In Stock

Plasmaglow Light Bulb - Yellow, Direct Fit                                              
 Color/ Finish:White
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-WH
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-BL
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H3
Part Number:H3P
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Yellow
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-YW
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H7
Part Number:H7L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9006
Part Number:9006H
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PR
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9007
Part Number:9007L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H1
Part Number:H1L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Pink
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PI
Availability: In Stock

Plasmaglow Light Bulb - Blue, Direct Fit                                                
 Color/ Finish:White
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-WH
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-BL
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H3
Part Number:H3P
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Yellow
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-YW
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H7
Part Number:H7L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9006
Part Number:9006H
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PR
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9007
Part Number:9007L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H1
Part Number:H1L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Pink
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PI
Availability: In Stock

Plasmaglow Light Bulb - Blue, Direct Fit                                                
 Color/ Finish:White
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-WH
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-BL
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H3
Part Number:H3P
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Yellow
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-YW
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H7
Part Number:H7L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9006
Part Number:9006H
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PR
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9007
Part Number:9007L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H1
Part Number:H1L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Pink
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PI
Availability: In Stock

Plasmaglow Light Bulb - Purple, Direct Fit                                              
 Color/ Finish:White
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-WH
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-BL
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H3
Part Number:H3P
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Yellow
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-YW
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H7
Part Number:H7L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9006
Part Number:9006H
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PR
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9007
Part Number:9007L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H1
Part Number:H1L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Pink
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PI
Availability: In Stock

Plasmaglow Light Bulb - Blue, Direct Fit                                                
 Color/ Finish:White
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-WH
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-BL
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H3
Part Number:H3P
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Yellow
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-YW
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H7
Part Number:H7L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9006
Part Number:9006H
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PR
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9007
Part Number:9007L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H1
Part Number:H1L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Pink
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PI
Availability: In Stock

Plasmaglow Light Bulb - Blue, Direct Fit                                                
 Color/ Finish:White
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-WH
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-BL
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H3
Part Number:H3P
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Yellow
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-YW
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H7
Part Number:H7L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9006
Part Number:9006H
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PR
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9007
Part Number:9007L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H1
Part Number:H1L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Pink
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PI
Availability: In Stock

Plasmaglow Light Bulb - Pink, Direct Fit                                                
 Color/ Finish:White
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-WH
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-BL
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H3
Part Number:H3P
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Yellow
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-YW
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H7
Part Number:H7L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9006
Part Number:9006H
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Purple
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PR
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:9007
Part Number:9007L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Blue
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:H1
Part Number:H1L
Availability: In Stock
 Color/ Finish:Pink
 Product Fit:Direct Fit
 Quantity Sold:Set of 2
 Anticipated Ship Out Time:1-2 Business Days
 Bulb Type:194/168
Part Number:194LED-PI
Availability: In Stock
```

Comment: i tried it before, and the problem i can not get the title as same as when i run on browser the link. In 2nd request, it displays the title : Plasmaglow Light Bulb - White, Direct Fit but on browser and 1st request it displays: Plasmaglow Light Bulb 2002 Honda Civic. i can not get exact title in 2nd request.